# Игрок, зашедший на сервер, передвигается рывками, как исправить?

Tags: c++, сеть, boost, asio

Написал сервер для своей игры, который получает координаты и направление взгляда персонажа каждого игрока и отсылает их остальным игрокам, чтобы те могли видеть друг друга.

Мой персонаж передвигается плавно. Игра занимает 20-25% ЦП и 300Мбайт оперативной памяти и не лагает вовсе. При этом всём рывки остаются, даже если запустить сервер и клиент локально ("посмотреть на себя со второго окна игры").

Сервер/клиент асинхронные TCP, сериализую данные через json парсер. Если два игрока на сервере, то сообщения длиной максимум 70-80 символов.

Можете подсказать как решить проблему?

Что происходит в клиенте игры (код):

```
try {
    if (argc == 4) {
        ip::tcp::resolver resolver(service);
        auto endpoints = resolver.resolve(argv[1], argv[2]); //ввожу IP и порт
        Client::ptr client = Client::start(endpoints, argv[3]); //коннект к серверу, а затем обработка отправки/чтения сообщений

        std::thread thr(netStart); //netStart запускает service.run() и всё
        thr.detach();
    }
}
catch (std::exception& e)
{
    std::cerr << e.what() << std::endl;
    return -1;
}

//когда клиент присоединится к серверу, начинается инициализация игры и основной цикл
GameInit();
GameCycle();
```

Сетевая часть клиента игры:

```
boost::shared_ptr<Client> Client::start(const ip::tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoints, const std::string & username)
{
    ptr new_(new Client(username));
    new_->start(const ip::tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoints);
    return new_;
}

Client::start(const ip::tcp::resolver::results_type& endpoints) {
    async_connect(sock_, endpoints, boost::bind(&Client::on_connect, shared_from_this(), _1));
}

void Client::on_connect(const boost::system::error_code & err)
{
    if (!err) {
        std::cout << "Connected to: " << sock_.remote_endpoint().address().to_string() << ":" << sock_.remote_endpoint().port() << std::endl;
        start();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "Failed to connect: " << err.message() << std::endl;
        stop();
    }
}

void Client::start()
{
    send_data(); //сериализует данные и вызывает async_write_some
}
```

В функции on_accept вызываю start(), если нет ошибок и в ней зацикливаю async_write_some и async_read_some т.е в start() вызывается функция async_write_some, если отправилось успешно, то в конце функции вызывается async_read_some (клиент игры читает данные других игроков, которые ему присылает сервер), затем снова async_write_some.

На сервере процесс тот же самый, но для каждого клиента.

Для парсинга json использую property tree, затем ptree вывожу в std::streamstring, делаю для него header, содержащий количество символов сообщения(пакета?) и гружу таким образом:

```
std::string outbound_data_;
std::string outbound_header_;

std::vector<boost::asio::const_buffer> buffers;
    buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outbound_header_));
    buffers.push_back(boost::asio::buffer(outbound_data_));
    boost::asio::async_write(sock_, buffers, boost::bind(&Client::on_send_data, shared_from_this(), _1, _2));
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/88888/discussion-on-question-by-de74ttempt------).